# awk condition for first line replacement

Tags: bash, shell, unix, awk

I have a shell that replace the first line of this file :

```
TABLE;APGFBEBA; ;
NoSS;CHAR(13);N° assuré;
DtDebExo;CHAR(8);Date début;
```

By this one :

```
01 APGFBEBA.
```

But i also have files that originally looks like this :

```
Table;APGFNOJF; ; ;
```

So i tried to add an "OR" condition to my awk command so i can replace those lines the same way i did it for the one above, but unfortunately it do not work

Here is my awk command :

```
awk -F ';' '
$1=="TABLE" && $3==" " || $1=="TABLE" && $4==" " {
  printf "01 %s.\n\n", $2;
  next
}
```

The first condition works, but not the second one

Comment: `awk -F ';' 'toupper($1)=="TABLE" {printf "01 %s.\n\n", $2}' file` should work for both lines.

Comment: subject includes the phrase *`first line replacement`* ... does this mean you only want to change the **first** line of a file? if so I'd suggest updating the question with sample input that shows the first few lines of the file and then show the expected output for those same *few lines*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Converting my comment to answer so that solution is easy to find for future visitors.

You don't need `||` conditions to match both lines as

```
awk -F ';' '
toupper($1)=="TABLE"  && $3 == " " {
   printf "01 %s.\n\n", $2
}' file
```

should work for both the lines.